# Styling kentico ASP.Net Template

Tags: asp.net, css, kentico

I created an ASP.Net template and styling it to suite has not been fun as I could not locate the main stlyesheet. The template is for Corporate site. Better still, can I just edit the Corporate site template to suit my design? All I need to do  is locate the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Go to SiteManager->Development->CSS stylesheets and edit Corporate site style sheet. See the [documentation](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/css_overview.htm).

Comment: Alternatively you can edit the stylesheet directly from CMS Desk. (Page -> Properties -> General)